# Advantage of MAPE loss function over MAE and RMSE

Tags: machine-learning, math, statistics

I'm reading this article: [Rolling Window Regression: a Simple Approach for Time Series Next value Predictions](https://medium.com/making-sense-of-data/time-series-next-value-prediction-using-regression-over-a-rolling-window-228f0acae363) and he explains there the difference between five loss functions:

> The first question is asking how do we measure success? We do this via
>   a loss function, where we try to minimize the loss function. There are
>   several loss functions, and they are different pros and cons.

I managed to understand the first two loss functions:

> 1. MAE ( Mean absolute error) — here all errors, big and small, are treated equally
> 2. Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) — this penalizes large errors due to the squared term. For example, with errors [0.5, 0.5] and [0.1, 0.9],
>      MSE for both will be 0.5 while RMSE is 0.5 and. 0.45.

But I don't understand the thrid one:

> 3. MAPE ( Mean Absolute Percentage Error) — Since #1 and #2 depending on the value range of the target variable, they cannot be compared
>      across datasets. In contrast, MAPE is a percentage, hence relative. It
>      is like accuracy in a classification problem, where everyone knows 99%
>      accuracy is pretty good.

1. Why depending on the value range of the target variable, they cannot be compared across datasets?
2. Why is MAPE better than them?

I don't understand his explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is - MAPE uses percentage.

In both MAE and RMSE I get the mean error or the root of the mean error of a dataset. Therefore in one dataset, let's say beer prices, the numbers will be small, whereas in another dataset, let's say house prices, the numbers will be large. Therefore I cannot compare the success of MAE/RMSE on one dataset to their success on another.

In contrast to them, MAPE represents the error in percentage and therefore it's not relative to the size of the numbers in the data itself, and therefore I can compare its success on the beer prices and the house prices datasets.